# The number of ways to select a school musical

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Four boys and four girls try out for a school musical. The number of ways that the director can select a male lead singer, a female lead singer, and 3 students to provide vocal back-ups is

my work:$${_4C_1} \times {_4C_1} \times {_6C_3}$$

That would be $4\times 4\times 20 = 320$ ways

is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct. .

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

The ways of selecting a male lead singer out of $4$ male singers $\large ={^4C_1}$

The ways of selecting a female lead singer out of $4$ female singers $\large ={^4C_1}$

Number of left singers $4+4-2=6$. The ways of selecting $3$ students out of $6$ for vocal back ups $$={^6C_3}$$

The total ways of selecting musical team
$$={^4C_1}\times {^4C_1}\times {^6C_3}=320$$

Comment: ok thankyou,because coffeemath said my answer was wrong so I was doubting myself. Do you mind helping me in another question ,heres the question:Using the letters in the word ENGLISH, how many distinguishable 4 letter arrangements can be formed if no letters can be repeated and the first letter must be E? I got an answer of 360 .is that correct?

Comment: @TanvirJoshi Please post that as a separate question.

Comment: it wont let me post it here

Comment: @TanvirJoshi: answer of your question: select three other letters by $^6C_3$ ways & arrange them by $3!$ ways so total ways  $^6C_3\times 3!=120$

Comment: is this for the english question I asked above?

Comment: yes, this is answer of your second question asked in comment

Comment: @TanvirJoshi in the future, please do not post additional questions in the comments. If you have more questions, please post them as separate questions. So, when you say, "it wont let me post it here", that is by design. The community prefers separate questions to be asked separately.

Comment: ok thankyou,i had one last question if you could help me with please I would really appreciate it. Heres the question:Determine the number of permutations of all the letters of the word STATISTICIAN if the arrangement must begin with C and end in N.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot

Comment: @TanvirJoshi: Answer of your last question: After selecting $C$ as first letter & $N$ as last letter, total letters left are $2A,3I,2S,3T $ so total linear arrangements $(10!)/(2!3!2!3!)=25200$. Now, I request you not to repeat questions on question.

Comment: @TanvirJoshi I answered your other question.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot i posted a question and would really appreciate it if you could look at my work and see if its right,and show me the answer heres the link to the question i posted:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3707715/795253